# Debugging solidity function

Tags: solidity, web3js

How can i call second function so that it could return key_Number and key name ?

```
function TransferKey (address receiver, string _name, uint Key_Number) 
    public  {
    name = _name;
    assert (Keys[msg.sender] != 0);
    if(Keys[msg.sender] <= Key_Number)  return;
    //This function is anytime a node wanner send keys
    //It checks if the keys of the sender is less than the Key_Number
    //This code reduces the number of keys in possession of the the sender by one
    Keys[msg.sender] -= Key_Number;
    //This code also increases the address by the number sent  
    Keys[receiver] += Key_Number; 
    emit sent( msg.sender, receiver,Key_Number);
```

*AND this is function that should return the uint and the string value of the transfer key*

```
    function NumberOfKeysInPossession(address account) public view returns ( uint, string ) {
         //This function return Key_Number of a given account.
         return Keys[account] , keys[_name];
         //It checks the number of keys owned by a particular account.
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can i call second function so that it could return key_Number and key name ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to provide `_name` as a parameter in `NumberOfKeysInPossession()` . I suppose you intended to use _name from `transferKey()`(just an assumption without any knowledge of the rest of your smart contract's logic) but there it's out of scope, of course. And by the way, the mapping `Keys`already exists, how can/ should there be another `keys` in lowercase ? Anyway, it's expecting a parameter which your function doesn't provide.

Try going with something like

```
function NumberOfKeysInPossession(address account someType _someParam) public view returns ( uint, string ) {
     //This function return Key_Number of a given account.
     return Keys[account] , someMapping[_someParamBeingOfExpectedType];
     //It checks the number of keys owned by a particular account.
}
```